# Does invalidating AWS cloudfront cache for a file clears the origin shield cache of it as well?

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, amazon-cloudfront, cdn, dynamic-content

I have enabled origin shield for my cloudfront distribution. Does invalidating a file invalidated origin shield cache also in addition to the edge caches ?

I checked with different vpns, added server timing headers but couldn't come to a solution

Comment: May be you can leverage this OriginSheild to identify if the request is served from Origin Sheild or not. This is from AWS docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/origin-shield.html
Cache hits from Origin Shield appear as OriginShieldHit in the x-edge-detailed-result-type field in CloudFront logs. Origin Shield leverages Amazon CloudFront’s regional edge caches. If a request is routed from a CloudFront edge location to the regional edge cache that is acting as Origin Shield, it is reported as a Hit in the logs, not as an OriginShieldHit.

Answer (score 0):

Invalidations should effect for all caches including origin shield, otherwise it would still serve stale content.